# Per-project Sublime Text 2 settings

Tags: settings, sublimetext2

My per-project Sublime Text 2 settings seem to not override the global settings.
I added this lines inside `"settings"` inside my `myproj.sublime-project`:

```
"file_exclude_patterns": ["config.xml"]
"folder_exclude_patterns": [".git", ".metadata"]
```

but that did not prevent those folders/files from showing up on the project sidebar.
None of the files/folders above are mentioned in my global settings.

Is it a known Sublime issue? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to add those settings under `folders` (example taken from [here](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/projects.html)):

```
{
    "folders":
    [
        {
            "path": "src",
            "folder_exclude_patterns": ["backup"]
        },
        {
            "path": "docs",
            "name": "Documentation",
            "file_exclude_patterns": ["*.css"]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: God, that's awkward! I spent the last 20 mins on that page :)